# How can a SlidingDrawer be animated?

Tags: android, slidingdrawer

I try to open/close my slidingdrawer with `animateOpen()` and `animateClose()`, but it seems it opens and closes instantaneously, like `open()` and `close()`. What's wrong?

I've seen that SlidingDrawer can't be customized (can't be animated with custom animation for instance, even not with custom open/close duration). Do I have to copy SlidingDrawer's code just to change the animation duration?

Thanks

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.home);        

    // Open and close banner
    final SlidingDrawer banner = (SlidingDrawer) findViewById(R.id.banner);
    banner.animateOpen();
    Handler handler = new Handler(); 
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() { 
         public void run() { 
              banner.animateClose();
         } 
    }, 2000); 

    //...

}
```

**EDIT**

Doing

```
final SlidingDrawer banner = (SlidingDrawer) findViewById(R.id.banner);
final Animation hideBanner = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.hide_banner);
banner.setAnimation(showBanner);
```

animates the handler only, even though I don't do `banner.animateOpen()` or `banner.startAnimation(showbanner)`!

Comment: Try using setAnimation(...) to set an animation on your banner object before using animateOpen() / animateClose()

Comment: I tried: only the handler is animated. The content is not visible :(

Answer (score 3):

[This youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4H01D9hYVyw) shows a sliding drawer with a custom animation. You should be able to use or modify [this code](http://www.mediafire.com/?57njuihinai6219) to solve your issue...